# Retrieve field name form Value in Elastic Search

Tags: json, search, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

Here is my Json Document which I want to Index and Search

```
{
    "BookName":"Book1",
    "ISBN":"978-3-16-148410-0",
    "PageCount":"504",
    "Chapters":{
        "Chapter1":"Chapter_Content",
        "Chapter2":"Chapter_Content",
        "Chapter3":"Chapter_Content",
        "Chapter4":"Chapter_Content",
        "Chapter5":"Chapter_Content",
        "Chapter6":"Chapter_Content",
        ...
        "ChapterN":"Chapter_Content"
    }
}

{
    "BookName":"Book2",
    "ISBN":"548-1-13-344410-1",
    "PageCount":"504",
    "Chapters":{
        "Chapter1":"Chapter_Content",
        "Chapter2":"Chapter_Content",
        "Chapter3":"Chapter_Content",
        ...
        "ChapterN":"Chapter_Content"

    }
}
```

I want to retrieve chapter number from this documents, like if I search for any of Chapter_Content  It should return ChapterName(Chapter1,Chapter2...)

### Here is an Example:

```
{
    "BookName":"Book1",
    "ISBN":"978-3-16-148410-0",
    "PageCount":"504",
    "Chapters":{
        "Chapter1":"This textbook was written with two primary objectives. The ﬁrst is to introduce...",
        "Chapter2":"C is a general-purpose programming language, and is used for writing programs in many diﬀerent domains, such as ...",
        "Chapter3":"The following program is the traditional ﬁrst program presented in introductory C courses and textbooks...",
        "Chapter4":"The following program produces identical output to the previous example. It shows ...",
        "Chapter5":"This text is organised in a sequential fashion—from fundamentals to higher-level constructs and software design issues. The core language is covered in Chapters 2–5 and...",
        "Chapter6":"Identiﬁers (i.e., variable names, function names, etc) are made up of letters and digits, and are case-sensitive. The ﬁrst ...",
        ...
        "ChapterN":"Other Content..."
    }
}
```

Now In above json If I search for **traditional** it should return **Chapter3** 
or if I search for **case-sensitive** it should return **Chapter6**.

--End of Example--

I  have tried highlight method but using highlight I have to Store data and that will increase the size of my index and as per my mapping I have excluded Chapters field from source.

Is there any better solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you brief your question and in your json where is the Chapter Name

Comment: @KARTHEEKGUMMALURI
In my json Chapter1,Chapter2... is it self a chapter name.

Comment: @KARTHEEKGUMMALURI
And I have added a Example in my question! That will help you understand question better.
Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get name of field in result from ElasticSearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656884/get-name-of-field-in-result-from-elasticsearch)